# Mask dataframe matching multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I would like mask (or assign 'NA') the value of a column in a dataframe if two conditions are met. This would be relatively straightforward if the conditions were performed row-wise, with something like:

```
mask = ((df['A'] < x) & (df['B'] < y))
df.loc[mask, 'C'] = 'NA'
```

but I'm having some trouble figuring out of how to perform this task in my dataframe, which is structured more or less like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': (188, 750, 1330, 1385, 188, 750, 810, 1330, 1385),
                     'B': (2, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5, 3, 7, 2),
                     'C': ('foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar') })

    A    B C
0   188  2 foo
1   750  5 foo
2   1330 7 foo
3   1385 2 foo
4   188  5 bar
5   750  5 bar
6   810  3 bar
7   1330 7 bar
8   1385 2 bar
```

The values in column 'A' when `'C' == 'foo'` should also be found when `'C' == 'bar'` (something like an index), although it can have missing data in both 'foo' and 'bar'. How can I mask (or assign 'NA') the rows of column 'B' if both 'foo' and 'bar' are lower than 5 or any of them is missing? In the example above the output would be something like:

```
    A    B C
0   188  2  foo
1   750  5  foo
2   1330 7  foo
3   1385 NA foo
4   188  5  bar
5   750  5  bar
6   810  NA bar
7   1330 7  bar
8   1385 NA bar
```

Comment: `although it can have missing data in both 'foo' and 'bar'`....`or any of them is missing`. What does that mean precisely?

Comment: Your desired output can be achieved via `df.loc[df['B'] < 5, 'B'] = np.nan` (notice: use `np.nan` instead of `'NA'` for numeric data). But it's not clear this is what you want.

Comment: Relative to the missing data an example would be for example row 6 which is found when C == 'bar' but not when C == 'foo'. That's only filtering for one row at a time. I'd like something like that but that combines by group? on column C.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you provide an example where `df.loc[df['B'] < 5, 'B'] = np.nan` does *not* work? Right now your example doesn't seem to *demonstrate the problem*.

Comment: Excellent edit, thank you.

Comment: I see. I updated the dataframe in the question to try to reflect this issue. Using your code would mask any number on column B if the number is < 5, but what I'm really looking for is to mask column B  if the value of B is < 5 when `C == foo` and `C == bar`. I guess something in the workings of groupby('A') would do the trick but I haven't figured it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution. The idea is to construct two Boolean masks, `m1` and `m2`, from two mapping series, `s1` and `s2`. Then use [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) to mask series `B`.

```
# create separate mappings for foo and bar
s1 = df.loc[df['C'] == 'foo'].set_index('A')['B']
s2 = df.loc[df['C'] == 'bar'].set_index('A')['B']

# use -np.inf to cover missing mappings
m1 = df['A'].map(s1).fillna(-np.inf).lt(5)  
m2 = df['A'].map(s2).fillna(-np.inf).lt(5)

df['B'] = df['B'].mask(m1 & m2)

print(df)

      A    B    C
0   188  2.0  foo
1   750  5.0  foo
2  1330  7.0  foo
3  1385  NaN  foo
4   188  5.0  bar
5   750  5.0  bar
6   810  NaN  bar
7  1330  7.0  bar
8  1385  NaN  bar
```

Comment: Excellent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution using [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) and some other ideas borrowed from jpp's answer:

```
# create a mapping test for each group from column 'A'
fmap = df.groupby(['A']).apply(lambda x: all(x['B'] < 5))
# and generate a new masking map from that
mask_map = df['A'].map(fmap)
# then just mask the values in the original DF
df['B'] = df['B'].mask(mask_map)

      A    B    C
0   188  2.0  foo
1   750  5.0  foo
2  1330  7.0  foo
3  1385  NaN  foo
4   188  5.0  bar
5   750  5.0  bar
6   810  NaN  bar
7  1330  7.0  bar
8  1385  NaN  bar
```

Comment: Nice solution :). I just recommend you use a different variable name than `mask`, so it doesn't get confused with the `mask` method.